# How to deploy a referenced project onto an JBoss?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jboss, wildfly

I have a Java project "Project A" which runs on a JBoss 8.2 (Wildfly). I use Intellij do develop and run the project on a local Wildfly (using a run configuration). That works fine.

I have a second Java project "Project B", which is a simple library used by Project A. I have the following entry in the build.gradle-file of Project A:

```
compile project(':ProjectB')
```

If I run Project A (which access Project B) in Intellij java runtime (NOT on the local server), it works well. Project A calls Project B without any problems.

If I run Project A on the local wildfire (using my run configuration), I get a "NoClassDefFoundError" referring to the Project B.

Which is the best way, to deploy Project B on the wildfly, while I run Project A? Many thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add your jar(module b) as module in local standalone server on which you are running and add dependency in project A for it

Edit : 
steps to add module :
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7

My module.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="testsinglejar.specificpackage">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="specificpackage-0.0.1.jar" />         <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <!--
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="javax.api" />
        </dependencies> 
    -->
</module>
```

and then in you project edit jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>

        <dependencies>
                <module name="testsinglejar.specificpackage" />
        </dependencies>

    </deployment>


</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Apart from this to run in eclipse directly you can do as below
[image]

Comment: Can you give me some details? I know how the result should look at the end, but it's more about the "how to". How do I configure that project B creates a .jar and how I link that to Project A, without loosing the link  directly to the project?